# What do the setting need to be on my Nikon D5300 to use off camera flash using Younguo triggers?

Tags: nikon, camera, nikon-d5300

I have spent a few hours on this. The triggers are working and and are all on the same channel but I cannot get the flash to fire.

Comment: Which flash model? Which trigger model?

Comment: How do you know the triggers are working if the flash doesn't fire?

Comment: I don't know if this is a common problem, but I was using a remote/trigger set from a different company, and they wouldn't work if too close to each other.

Comment: Related to xiota's first question: does the trigger have a "test fire" button to allow you to isolate communication problems between the trigger and the flash from problems between the camera and the trigger?

Answer (score 1):

The camera settings shouldn't matter, but I don't use a D5x00 so I don't know what different settings it might have.

Make sure that:

- the flashes are in radio slave mode
- the trigger and the flashes are on the same radio channel
- the group to which the flashes are assigned is set to fire on the trigger

If all of these were already true, try turning everything off and then turning it back on in this sequence: flashes, then trigger, then camera. (Also make sure the trigger is already on the camera before you turn everything on.)

Comment: I'd add checking battery levels to the list.

Comment: At least one camera setting does matter -- It has to be set to use the flash.

Comment: Hear, hear... :)

Answer (score 0):

There should be 4 channels numbered as 1,2,3,4 in your trigger and in the flash. You should turned on the same number of channel in the Light & Trigger.

Example : Channel 2 turned on in the Trigger and Light.